# Negative string size (or size too big) (Argument Error) - ruby 1.8.6

Tags: ruby, t-sql, odbc, nvarchar, dbd

I am using ruby 1.8.6 and dbd-odbc 0.2.4.
I am trying to execute this query: 
`SELECT * FROM TABLE1`

Some of the fields in that table1 are type nvarchar(max). I am getting this error from ruby:

> *Negative string size (or size too big) (Argument Error)*

I have tried reinstalling the gem, tried adding this also `set textsize 1000`
but it's not helping. Any ideas?

Note: I have to use this version of ruby and gem(so pls don't suggest upgrading to higher version of ruby).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you have to use a Ruby version that is more than 9 years old?

Comment: Are you using Rails? If so, what version of rails are you using? You might want to find out if dbd-odbc is even supported on that version of Rails. Can you show the code you used to execute that query?